# Select rows where PO_ID has specific value in another column across all associated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below query that I am trying to manipulate so that I can query for all the rows per `BUSINESS_UNIT` and `PO_ID` that have a `CANCEL_STATUS` value of 'A' across all of it's associated rows.

I think an example might be the best way to show this. This is ordered by `BUSINESS_UNIT` and `PO_ID`:

[image]

The Green shaded rows (4 sets) are what I would want to include in the result-set because each of these `PO_ID` / `BUSINESS_UNIT` combinations rows have `CANCEL_STATUS` of `'A'`. I would want to exclude the rows/lines for `PO_ID` L010006793 (Highlighted as Red) because one of it's lines has a `CANCEL_STATUS` not equal to `'A'`.

```
SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.PO_ID, A.PO_STATUS, B.LINE_NBR, B.CANCEL_STATUS
FROM PS_PO_HDR A
INNER JOIN PS_PO_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.PO_ID = A.PO_ID
WHERE  --A.PO_ID = 'A030010686'
A.PO_STATUS NOT IN ('C','X','PX')
AND A.PO_DT >= '01-JAN-2019'
ORDER BY BUSINESS_UNIT, PO_ID, CANCEL_STATUS
```

I imagine I need to do some kind of aggregation to compare the count of the PO_ID/BUSINESS_UNIT rows with a `CANCEL_STATUS` value of 'A' and then compare that to the total number of rows for that `PO_ID`/ `BUSINESS_UNIT` and filter for the ones where these totals match, but maybe there is something more simplified that I'm overlooking...

Answer (score 1):

**A conditional windowed count would do nicely here:**

```sql
SELECT
    BUSINESS_UNIT,
    PO_ID,
    PO_STATUS,
    LINE_NBR,
    CANCEL_STATUS
FROM (
    SELECT
        ph.BUSINESS_UNIT,
        ph.PO_ID,
        ph.PO_STATUS,
        pl.LINE_NBR,
        pl.CANCEL_STATUS,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN pl.CANCEL_STATUS <> 'A' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY ph.BUSINESS_UNIT, ph.PO_ID) countNotA
    FROM PS_PO_HDR ph
    INNER JOIN PS_PO_LINE pl ON pl.BUSINESS_UNIT = ph.BUSINESS_UNIT AND pl.PO_ID = ph.PO_ID
    WHERE  --A.PO_ID = 'A030010686'
        ph.PO_STATUS NOT IN ('C','X','PX')
    AND ph.PO_DT >= '01-JAN-2019'
) t
WHERE countNotA = 0
ORDER BY BUSINESS_UNIT, PO_ID, CANCEL_STATUS
```

[Please choose sensible aliases, not `a` and `b`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: I tested this a little more and I only want the query to pull in a single Header row for each `BUSINESS_UNIT` / `PO_ID` combination. In cases where there are multiple lines this query is pulling in a row for each line and I only want it to output 1 (Header) row. So I believe I still need to reference the lines table (`PS_PO_LINE`) but I don't want to pull in the multiple rows for each line? How can I do that?

Comment: I tested this a little more and I only want the query to pull in a single Header row for each `BUSINESS_UNIT` / `PO_ID` combination. In cases where there are multiple lines this query is pulling in a row for each line and I only want it to output 1 (Header) row. So I believe I still need to reference the lines table (`PS_PO_LINE`) and check each line row for `CANCEL_STATUS` but I don't want to pull in multiple rows for each line on a PO? How can I do that?